# How to control Activity FragmentTransaction from within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Im sure this question is pretty basic but im new.
Now I have a FragmentTransaction under my main activity (see it below), I would like to be able to perform "replace" from within one of these fragments. I believe it would involve getActivity() but im not really sure about how to do that?

It would be nice if anybody could give me an example, thanks in advance :)

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    {
        if(tab.getPosition()==0)
        {
        firstFragment frag = new firstFragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==1)
        {
        newsFragment frag = new newsFragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==2)
        {
        thirFragment frag = new thirFragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==3)
        {
        calendar frag = new calendar();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==6)
        {
        linksFragment frag = new linksFragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==5)
        {
        contactFragment frag = new contactFragment();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        }


}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO use the fragment transaction you do this :

```
                FragmentManager fmu = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ftu = fmu.beginTransaction();
                RSSFragment rssfrag;
                ftu.replace(R.id.frame_fragment, rssfrag).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class variable rootActivity, the instantiate in your onCreate() method.

```
public class yourclass
Activity rootActivity;
public void onCreate(){
     super.onCreate();
     rootActivity = getActivity();
}
```